# Changing an element in one list changes multiple lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of List say `mysolution`:

```
>>>mySolution
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> mySolution[0][0] = 1    
>>> mySolution
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Intended output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

why is it that all the 1st elements in my list of list's is being changed to 1?
I would only like to change the first element of the first list to 1.

Comment: Oh that pesky `n * list` operator! I honestly wouldn't mind if it threw an exception when mutable types were detected ..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What matters is how you created your original `mysolution` list. As it seems, it contains four times the same list which is why changing it once will make it change in all four locations.

To initialize independent zero-filled lists like that, you can do the following:

```
mysolution = [[0] * 4 for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: mySolution=[0]*4
mySolution = [mySolution]*4

Comment: @Pavan: That won't work because it's the same list four times.  poke's solution aviods that.

Answer (score 8):

It's quite possible that you created the list like this:

```
mySolution = [0]*4
mySolution = [mySolution]*4
```

Or equivalently:

```
mySolution = [[0]*4]*4
```

Either of the above snippets will create a list with four sublists which are copies of *the exact, same sublist*, so any modification on one sublist will be reflected on the others - they're one and the same. The solution is to create four *different* sublists:

```
mySolution = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
mySolution = [[0]*4 for _ in xrange(4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because all the contained lists are actually *the same list*. When you do:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 0]
my_solution = [l, l, l]
```

Then, `my_solution[0]`, `my_solution[1]`, and `my_solution[2]` are references to the same object (`l`).

If you modify the list in one location, it changes everywhere. That is because lists are *mutable* objects.

Instead, use multiple lists:

```
l1 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
l2 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
l3 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
my_solution = [l1, l2, l3]
```

Which will work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

please note that this is doing fine:

```
mySolution = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
mySolution[0][0] = 1    
print mySolution

>>> 
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

it all depends on how you initialized your `solution`. this

```
mySolution = [[0, 0, 0, 0]]*4
mySolution[0][0] = 1    
print mySolution
```

gives

```
>>> 
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
```

because here each array `[0, 0, 0, 0]` in `mySolution` is a copy of initialization array `[0, 0, 0, 0]` in `[[0, 0, 0, 0]]*4`. if you change first element of first array, copy of it also change.

with this initialization `mySolution = [[0, 0, 0, 0] for x in range(4)]` you are not copying the array but appending `[0,0,0,0]` four times, giving the result that you are expecting.