# Why do I get two different behaviours depending on how I create 2D Arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I'm trying to edit a value in a 2D array.

Just the value at `[0][0]` but when I edit it, it propagates to all the values at `[x][0]` and I don't understand why.

I then copied the exact line from an example that I found online and it works but I don't understand what the difference is.

I simplified both examples and they still don't have the same solutions. This doesn't add up.

```py
counter= 3*[4*[0]]
counter[0][3] = 7
print(counter)

T = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0,0,0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
T[0][3] = 7
print(T)
```

the top print statement gives:
`[[0, 0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 0, 7]]`

the bottom gives: 
`[[0, 0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`

but they should be the same.

Comment: You haven't said what `counter` is, so how can anyone answer?

Comment: Please provide the value of Counter.

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946728/changing-an-element-in-one-list-changes-multiple-lists) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739552/2d-list-has-weird-behavor-when-trying-to-modify-a-single-value) and above all, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: It's quite obvious what is going on without even knowing how `counter` has been defined.  'counter' is likely a 'list of lists', but it's not a list of unique lists but rather a list of multiple pointers to the same embedded list.  So when you change that one embedded list with a reference pulled from one element of the outer list, you'll see that same change when you reference that same sub-list with any of the other references in the outer list.  In your second example, you have created a list of lists where each embedded list is truly unique, and so changing one does not change the others.